# How to append textbox value along with dropdown values and vice versa using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how to append text from the selected dropdown value and also the the text from textbox into a single string.

I need results in JQuery and i found this [link](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/03/add-textbox-value-to-dropdownlist-or.html), which doesn't work.
Thank You in advance.

here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z97d523/4/) for more information.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <select type="text" id="rules">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="client_id ">Client_ID</option>
            <option value="employee_id ">Employee_ID</option>
            <option value="salary ">Salary</option>
        </select>
        <select type="text" id="options">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="= =">Equals</option>
            <option value="! =">Not Equals</option>
            <option value="<">Less Than</option>
            <option value=">">Greater Than</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your value here" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'enter your text'" class="inputValues" id="inputValues" value="" />
        <select type="text" id="options">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="|| ">OR</option>
            <option value="&& ">AND</option>
            <option value=") ">END</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Generate formula" id="generate"/><br>
        <input type="text" class="summary" id="input" value="" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Script:

```
function summarise(container, what, sumClass) {
    var els = container.querySelectorAll(what),
        sumTo = container.querySelector(sumClass),
        vals = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i < len; i++) {
        vals.push(els[i].value);
    }
    sumTo.value = vals.join(' ').trim();
}

var fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset');

for (var i = 0, len = fieldsets.length; i < len; i++) {
    fieldsets[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
        summarise(this, 'select', '.summary');
    }, false);
}
```

The output should be something like this:
for "Client_ID(dd) Equals 708 OR Employee_ID Not Equals 1025 END"
(client_id == "708"|| employee_id ! = "1025" )

Sorry all for not being clear in my question for the first time and updating it later.
http://jsfiddle.net/Dd3ee/ similar work

Comment: Where is the `summarise()` function call?

Comment: What should the generated formula look like?

Comment: @Ranjith:
did you mean similar function like:
bind('keypress blur', function ()
?
I'm fairly new to JQuery, so i'm still learning. and i didn't find any resources regarding [summarise()](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=summarise()%20jquery)

Comment: Simply your code with my answer or Umesh patil answer

Comment: Hi, is there any way which could do the vice versa part, if i edit the text, it should reflect in the dropdown too.
Thanks

Comment: What you mean if you edit in text box then append with where? In which dropdown? You mean new `option` in `select`?

Comment: So if i selected "client_id  ==  54" and later i changed the outpout text box to !=, i want my dropdown which says 'equals' should be changed to 'not equals'.
I know it requires lot of validation, but a start is what i'm looking for.
Thank You very much for your patience.

Comment: `later i changed the outpout text box to !=` is it dropdown right?

Comment: Yes, relational operators are from dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've improved your code a little with jQuery.

```js
function summarise(container, what, sumClass) {
    var $sumTo = $(sumClass),
        $els = $(container).find("input,select").not($sumTo, $("#generate")),
        vals = [];
    $els.each(function() {
        vals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $sumTo.val(vals.join(' ').trim());
}
/*$("#generate").click(function() {

            $('#generate').append($("<option>" + $('#Text1').val() + "</option>"));*/
var fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset');

for (var i = 0, len = fieldsets.length; i < len; i++) {
    fieldsets[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
        summarise(this, 'select', '.summary');
    }, false);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <select type="text" id="rules">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="client_id ">Client_ID</option>
            <option value="employee_id ">Employee_ID</option>
            <option value="salary ">Salary</option>
        </select>
        <select type="text" id="options">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="= =">Equals</option>
            <option value="! =">Not Equals</option>
            <option value="<">Less Than</option>
            <option value=">">Greater Than</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your value here" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'enter your text'" class="inputValues" id="inputValues" value="" />
        <select type="text" id="options">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="|| ">OR</option>
            <option value="&& ">AND</option>
            <option value=") ">END</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit"  value="Generate formula" id="generate"/><br>
        <input type="text" class="summary" id="input" value="" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Edit vice versa**

Here is more optimized version http://jsfiddle.net/6z97d523/13/. I've removed duplicated id's and added classes to watch for their change.

```js
function summarise($container, sumClass) {
    var $sumTo = $(sumClass),
        $els = $container.find(".watch"),
        vals = [];
    $els.each(function() {
        vals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $sumTo.val(vals.join(' ').trim());
}

var $fieldset = $("fieldset");
$fieldset.on("change", ".watch", function() {
    summarise($fieldset, '.summary');
});

$(".summary").change(function() {
    var vals = $(this).val().split(" ");
    $fieldset.find(".watch").each(function(i) {
        $(this).val(vals[i]);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <select type="text" class="watch" id="rules">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="client_id">Client_ID</option>
            <option value="employee_id">Employee_ID</option>
            <option value="salary">Salary</option>
        </select>
        <select type="text" class="watch" id="options">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="==">Equals</option>
            <option value="!=">Not Equals</option>
            <option value="<">Less Than</option>
            <option value=">">Greater Than</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="watch" placeholder="Enter your value here" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'enter your text'" class="inputValues" id="inputValues" value="" />
        <select type="text" class="watch" id="statement">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="||">OR</option>
            <option value="&&">AND</option>
            <option value=")">END</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit"  value="Generate formula" id="generate"/><br>
        <input type="text" class="summary" id="input" value="" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i was just looking for this.
I'll update further to work with the button text.

Comment: Hi, is there any way which could do the vice versa part, if i edit the text, it should reflect in the dropdown too.
Thanks

Comment: You could remove spaces from option values ("==" instead of "= ="). Then you can take the value of the resuted filed. Split it by spaces ( var values = $("#input").val().split(" ") )  and you would get an array of values for your inputs. Then you just need set these values to your fileds. Example: $("#rules").val(values[0])

Comment: the vice versa part is where if it change the client_id to employee_id after the result is generated, i want the value in the dropdown to be reverted to employee_id, but i clicked on your updated fiddle, and it is not working.
Once the result is generated, i changed the client_id to salary and did a tab and it changed the result back to client_id.

Answer (score 0):

This will help,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#generate").click(function(){
            var final_string = $("#rules").val() + ' ' + $("#options1").val() + ' ' +  $("#options2").val() + ' ' +  $("#inputValues").val();
            $("#input").val(final_string);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank You Umesh, i used your code along with Ranjith and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to your reference, I find the solution for you.

Don't repetitive the `id` for more than one element. I modified your code

```
 <select type="text" id="conditinal_options">
    <option value="">- select one -</option>
    <option value="==">Equals</option>
    <option value="!=">Not Equals</option>
    <option value="<">Less Than</option>
    <option value=">">Greater Than</option>
</select>

$('#rules, #conditinal_options, #inputValues, #options').on('keyup change', function() {

    $('#input').val($('#rules').val() + ' ' +
                             $('#conditinal_options').val() + ' ' +
                             $('#inputValues').val() + ' ' +
                             $('#options').val() );
});
```

**[Here is your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z97d523/7/)**

Comment: along with umesh's answer, it worked fine for me. 
+1 for cleaning ID repetitive tip.

Comment: Hi Ranjith, i would like to have a vice versa in JQuery version.
Tim gave me in js: http://jsfiddle.net/6z97d523/13/ 
JQuery looks more cleaner and less loc.

Answer (score 0):

There's just single problem with **`what`** argument in your summarise function:

```
function summarise(container, what, sumClass) {
    var els = container.querySelectorAll(what),
    ...
}
```

Where **`what`** is set to *'select'* here:

```
summarise(this, 'select', '.summary');
```

So that it won't work with textfield.

All you need to do is to add `my-field` (or any) class to each `input` and `select` elements inside `fieldset`, and then update this line (replace *'select'* with *'.my-field'*):

```
summarise(this, '.my-field', '.summary');
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1nucsrx2/)

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/6z97d523/10/, going against the stream, since your original post was in plain JS. And I'm not going to rewrite the whole thing in jQuery. Besides jQuery is overdressed for this occasion.

I've added a more firm way to attach event handlers to the selects and the input.

```
var fieldset = document.querySelector('fieldset');
Array.prototype.map.call(fieldset.querySelectorAll("#inputValues, select"), function(element){
    element.addEventListener("change", function(){
        summarise(fieldset, "select, #inputValues", ".summary");
    }, false);
});
```

This makes advantage of the fact that you can select multiple elements with `querySelectorAll` by separating the `selectors` with a comma. A change event is added to all the selects and the input with id `inputValues`. We reuse this simple fact when we sent the query to the `summarise` function.

In this article you can find more about the method used for adding the event handlers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @Stephn_R, read the answer. The OP has posted plain javascript and asks us to do a rewrite of his entire code in jQuery, not going to do that. This works based upon his code.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstandings in the middle. I did edited my question couple of times, but i asked for JQuery from the beginning. Thanks for your effort @Mouser.

Comment: @raja777m, can you explain to me why you post some working code (except for one bit) in plain JS and want a full jQuery solution. Why not try to write the solution in jQuery yourself and come back to us when you get stuck combining the values?

Answer (score -1):

We can leverage a couple of jQuery and Javascript functions to do this with very little code:

```
function summarize(form) {
    var results = "";
    $(form).find(":input[type='text']").map(function(idx, el) {
        if(el.className !== 'summary') {
            results += el.value;
        }
    });
    return results.trim();
}

$('#myForm :input').change(function(e) {
    $('input.summary').val(summarize($('#myForm')));
});
```

And the HTML to go with it:

```
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <select type="text" id="rules">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="client_id ">Client_ID</option>
            <option value="employee_id ">Employee_ID</option>
            <option value="salary ">Salary</option>
        </select>
        <select type="text" id="options">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="= =">Equals</option>
            <option value="! =">Not Equals</option>
            <option value="<">Less Than</option>
            <option value=">">Greater Than</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your value here" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'enter your text'" class="inputValues" id="inputValues" value="" />
        <select type="text" id="options">
            <option value="">- select one -</option>
            <option value="|| ">OR</option>
            <option value="&& ">AND</option>
            <option value=") ">END</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit"  value="Generate formula" id="generate"/><br>
        <input type="text" class="summary" id="input" value="" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6z97d523/12/